# Ajax call repeating is not working in IE

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have called a ajax call for saving the data(140 sized characters) in to database and then again have a ajax call in success function of the first call. 
It is working fine in FF i,e when click that button it will be saved and then retrieved that data successfully(I need this data to show with timestamp). But in IE it is working fine only one time, means when click button the a set of data will be saved and then show ,but again click button saving another set of data, but not showing that data ,it is showing previous data.  any solution my code is

```
function save(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'saveNote.html?note=' + notes,
        success : function() {
            // showNote(); //this is also not working in IE
            setTimeout(function () { showNote(); }, 1000);
            document.getElementById('notes').value="";
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('my error = ' + thrownError);
            alert('my error1 = ' + ajaxOptions);
            alert('my error2 = ' + xhr);               
        }
    }); 
}

function showNote(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'getNote.html',
        method : "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data) {
            responseNote=data;
            showLabel(responseNote);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('my error = ' + thrownError);
            alert('my error1 = ' + ajaxOptions);
            alert('my error2 = ' + xhr);               
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the JS code that calls `save()` and `showNote()`?

Comment: actually it is saved in DB with timestamp successfully but not calling second ajax (for retrieving) while second set of data saving I mean clicking the button second time.

Comment: save() is calling from onclick of a button in jsp

Comment: In your `save()` function, where is `notes` coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE is known to cache the AJAX requests. Thus subsequent request generates same output. There are a number of ways to overcome this problem. Here are some:

Source: [Viralpatel's Blogs](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-cache-problem-in-ie/)

**1. Attach random number with request**

```
 $.ajax({
       url: url,
       data: inputs + '&ran=' + Math.rand(),
    )};
```

**2. Attach date with request**

```
$.ajax({
       url: url,
       data: inputs + '&time=' + new Date(),
    )};
```

**3. Disable jQuery cache**

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

I'll suggest you to use 3rd option.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes Ur right I want not only solution but also the cause of the problem. I thought it may be cache issue but I am not sure because I am the newer in programming side . Again thanks . I tried both now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because IE cached your request. In this case you add one extra parameter to your inputs for example date. This will make all your calls unique.

```
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       beforeSend: function (data) { },
       data: inputs + '&time=' + new Date(),
       success:  function (data) { },
       error: function (data) { }
    )};
```

This *time* parameter you can ignore on server side.

In your case it would be

```
function save(){
$.ajax({
    url : 'saveNote.html?note=' + notes + '&time=' + new Date(),
    success : function() {
        // showNote(); //this is also not working in IE
        setTimeout(function () { showNote(); }, 1000);
        document.getElementById('notes').value="";
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('my error = ' + thrownError);
        alert('my error1 = ' + ajaxOptions);
        alert('my error2 = ' + xhr);               
    }
  }); 
}

function showNote(){
 $.ajax({
    url : 'getNote.html' + '&time=' + new Date(),
    method : "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
        responseNote=data;
        showLabel(responseNote);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('my error = ' + thrownError);
        alert('my error1 = ' + ajaxOptions);
        alert('my error2 = ' + xhr);               
    }
 });
}
```

Please mark answer, if this is the answer you are looking for. Thanks.

Comment: actually it is saved in DB with timestamp successfully but not calling second ajax (for retrieving) while second set of data saving I mean clicking the button second time. it is showing previous data from cache. pls help me

Comment: While technically correct, there's a much easier way to do this. The jQuery `.ajax()` method has a `cache` option, which when set to `false` will automatically append this timestamp for you. If you're going to be performing a lot of ajax calls, and you want none (or only a very few) of them to be cached, you can also call `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` to set the cache property to false for all calls to the `.ajax()`,`.get()` and `.post()` methods.

Comment: Try the code that I have provided. It should work. If there is any issue please give the details.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure - Please do not spoon feed. Try to explain the concept and of the solution. Let the user understand the problem. :)

Comment: I did that at the starting of my answer only. This was a simple answer, and I was expecting it will be accepted quickly. But as there was no input, I thought Kandhi didn't get my answer.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure,@viralpatel, Thank for ur quick responce, now it working fine in both adding date() to data and method for clearing the cache. it is working fine.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't get the net service @ yastrday evng and @night that y the delay for responce. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Put this function before your ajax call is enough for IE 7 and 8**

```
$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
```